# Outputting PostgreSQL's bit type in SQuirreL results in "<Error>"

Tags: postgresql, squirrel-sql

When I try to output something as a bitstring ([PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-bitstring.html)) in SQuirreL...

```
SELECT ('1234'::bigint)::bit(16);
```

I get the following result:

```
    bit
-------
<Error>
```

Can this be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the type is not supported by SQuirreL, but adding another cast to `varchar` works:

```
SELECT ('1234'::bigint)::bit(16)::varchar;
```

Output:

```
varchar         
----------------
0000010011010010
```